# How do you remove all empty unused rows and columns at the right and bottom of your data range?

Tags: excel

I accidentally enlarged the data range I was working on and now the scroll bars on the sides and bottom won't reset. I had this problem before and I found out how to do it, but now I've forgotten :/ Does anyone know the trick, I think it involves using Ctrl+End to locate the last cell of the active worksheet but I can't quite recall.

This is for Excel btw.

Thank you.

Comment: Up-to-date Excel 2007/2010/2013 resets the rogue *last cell* to the usable data range when saved and closed (then reopened) as long as you do not have formatting in the blank cells and you have removed the errant value. For Excel 2003 see [Worksheet size extended - how do I reset](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/worksheet-size-extended-how-do-i-reset-it-to-the/f1386e98-fa6f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgid=d02464dd-0e70-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Goto cell A1 (not really necessary)
- Hit Alt-F11 to open VBA editor
- Open Immediate Window (if not already opened)
- Type: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`+`Enter` (there will be no response)
- Done (you can close VBA editor)

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know this was even a possible solution